# If I place a composite index on three columns and use them in the same query but in different places, will it still be effective?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

With the following table and index:

```
CREATE TABLE [Ticket]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [Title] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] CHARACTER VARYING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Severity] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [Priority] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY([Id])
);

CREATE INDEX [Ticket_Priority_Severity_CreatedOn_IX] ON [Ticket]([Priority], [Severity], [CreatedOn]);
```

Will the following query:

```
SELECT [Id]
FROM [Ticket]
WHERE [Priority] = 1
ORDER BY [Severity] DESC, [CreatedOn] ASC
```

make use of the entire composite index or only utilize the `[Priority]` part of the index?

I know that for a query that had all of the columns in the `WHERE` clause, the whole index would be used. I am unsure about the above case though!

Given the actual execution plan below, on a table with no statistics, I am not sure how to interpret it.

[image: Actual Execution Plan]

It does look like it used the index, but which parts? There is clearly a sort cost, but is that sorting by `[Severity]` and then `[CreatedOn]` after doing a seek on `[Priority]`?

Comment: Did you check the execution plan, kindly post it here.

Comment: @mr_eclair at your request, this has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may use the index, but it will only use the `Priority` part *efficiently* since you have the index sorted in a way that is not optimal for the query;

```
ORDER BY [Severity] DESC, [CreatedOn] ASC
```

vs

```
CREATE INDEX [Ticket_Priority_Severity_CreatedOn_IX] ON 
  [Ticket]([Priority], [Severity], [CreatedOn]);
```

[As you can see in this fiddle if you click the execution plan, the query is split into an index seek and a sort](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/985db/2).

Since `Severity` is sorted ascended, the index won't be (optimally) used for the sort. If you really want an optimal sort, index `Severity` descending as your query uses it;

```
CREATE INDEX [Ticket_Priority_Severity_CreatedOn_IX] ON 
  [Ticket]([Priority], [Severity] DESC, [CreatedOn]);
```

[An SQLfiddle with the fixed index](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/985db/1/0). Note that the whole query is now an index seek.

Note that the plan *may* look different for you depending on your data, but in general this is true, an index sorted the same way as the query accesses it will use the index better.

Comment: So, a sorted index sounds awfully similar to a clustered index but maybe not quite. Does it just sort the indexes in whatever kind of lookup table SQL Server uses and not the physical data like a clustered index does?

Comment: It works great. Perfect. Thank you. I also did not know about sqlfiddle, so you get an upvote for that too. I will be sure to read the full syntax definitions on MSDN from now on. It's pretty clear what it does!